# Accepting a variable number of arguments into a Laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Supposed I have the following route:

```
Route::post('api/{call}', array('as' => 'apiCaller', 'uses' => 'ApiController@apiCaller'));
```

I want this route to be able to call a variable API specified in the `call` argument. After the `call` argument, I want the requestor to be able to submit a post in the typical format of `key=value` with a variable number of arguments depending on the API requested.

How can I go about doing this? Should I just check the $_POST array sent with the request, or does Laravel have special requirements?

Comment: You will be fine.  You can access `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables with the [`Input`](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input) class. I really don't think I can elaborate much more, but if you have specific questions I can post an answer while elaborating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Input` class to get any user data from `$_POST` or `$_GET` for example:

```
Input::get('keyname'); // get only one item by keyname
Input::all(); // returns all user submitted data from all input sources
Input::only(array('key1', 'key2')); // Only these two mentioned
Input::except('_token'); // get all but _token
```

If you want the user to submit data (unlimited parameters) with url then you have to use `query string`, for example:

```
http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=valye2 // So on...
```

For this, you don't have to modify your `route`, just pass add the parameters in the `url`. To submit into `$_POST`, it doesn't required to pass the parameters with `url` but whaat ever method you use (POST/GET), to retrieve the user submitted data you can use same `Input` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Input class, as @Sam told you:

```
class ApiController
{

  public function apiCaller($call)
  {
     $inputs = Input::all();
     // now $inputs is an array with all the key=> value pair sent, or an empty
     // array if none has been passed
  }
}
```

This and more is all written here http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input